# C# Delegate Use Object field's value without reference

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a delegate that I define at runtime. I want it to check if a dictionary contains a particular key. One of the delegate parameters is a `ref` to the dictionary, so the dictionary is always the latest version (not a frozen copy).

However the key to lookup is an `object` field, but I don't want to pass it a `ref` to that object. I just want to grab the field value and use it as if it were a constant (frozen copy).

This is the exact code snippet. I pass in a ref to the netController, which allows me to check something is there using `ContainsID()`. The ID parameter comes from the `msg` object, but I just want to use the value without the reference to the container object.

```
Func<netController, bool> resolveFunc = delegate (netController nc)
{
    return nc.ObjectRegister.ContainsID(msg.parentObjectID);
};
```

`nc` is in scope in this delegate, but `msg` is not. Is this do-able, or does everything need to be passed in as a parameter?

Note: I say dictionary, but its actually a dictionary-like object. `ContainsID()` is a wrapper for `ContainsKey()`. Don't worry about this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an implicit capture of a variable by delegate, and it is definitely possible.

As long as `msg` is in scope outside the line that creates your delegate, C# would capture it, and let you use it inside your code:

```
Func<Controller,bool> MakeChecker(Message msg) {
    return nc => nc.ObjectRegister.ContainsID(msg.parentObjectID);
}
```

Above method captures `msg` implicitly from the context that creates the delegate, rather than passing it as a delegate parameter. I used lambda syntax in place of anonymous delegate syntax:

```
Func<Controller,bool> MakeChecker(Message msg) {
    return delegate (netController nc) {
        return nc.ObjectRegister.ContainsID(msg.parentObjectID);
    }
}
```

> How do I store this into a delegate?

Like this:

```
Message msg = ...
Func<Controller,bool> myChecker = MakeChecker(msg);
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by that syntax, shouldn't there be an assignment somewhere? How do I store this into a delegate?

Comment: Am I being thick or is it still missing something? ```Func<Controller,bool> MakeChecker(Message msg) {
    return nc => nc.ObjectRegister.ContainsID(msg.parentObjectID);
}``` doesn't complile for me. I'm using .net 2.5, sorry I forgot to mention. 

Message is a type which is not valid in the context.
Expected ; or =
Return statement is trying to return from the containing main function (and causing issues).

Comment: @Oliver I didn't realize you're on .NET 2.5. Lambda syntax has not been introduced until .NET 3.5. Please see the edit for an equivalent anonymous delegate syntax.